# Print all the files in a given folder and sub-folders without using recursion/stack

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, language-agnostic

I recently had an interview with a reputable company for the position of Software Developer and this was one of the questions asked:

"Given the following methods:

```
List subDirectories(String directoryName){ ... }; 
List filesInDirectory(String directoryName) { ... };
```

As the names suggest, the first method returns a list of names of immediate sub-directories in the input directory ('directoryName') and the second method returns a list of names of all files in this folder.

Print all the files in the file system."

I thought about it and gave the interview a pretty obvious recursive solution. She then told me to do it without recursion. Since recursion makes use of the call stack, I told her I will use an auxillary stack instead, at which point point she told me not to use a stack either. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to come up with a solution. I did ask how it can be done without recursion/stack, but she wouldn't say.

How can this be done?

Comment: is it allowed to store the full path name on a variable?

Comment: I am not sure.. I didn't ask this to the interviewer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use a queue and a BFS algorithm.

I guess some pseudo-code would be nice:

```
files = filesInDirectory("/")
foreach (file in files) {
   fileQ.append(file)
}

dirQ = subDirectories("/")
while (dirQ != empty) {
   dir = dirQ.pop
   files = filesInDirectory(dir)
   foreach (file in files) {
      fileQ.append(file)
   }
   dirQ.append(subDirectories(dir))
}

 while (fileQ != empty) {
   print fileQ.pop
 }
```

Comment: There's no point keeping a queue of files. You can just print their names out as soon as you find them. You really only need the queue of directories.

Comment: sure, all depends on needs, but the query is still satisfied: print out all files on a system using these 2 methods and no recursion.

Comment: The need is to get a job, I think; it's an interview question. I've done lots of interviews, and had I used a question like this, my immediate follow-up would be: "What do you think the total size of all the filenames in a filesystem is?" :) Just sayin'

Comment: sure, I can also want to optimize for speed, which this does since writing to standard out is costly.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, immediate sub-directories are only the directories in that folder. I mean if I=we have these three paths `/home/user`, `/home/config`  and `/home/user/u001`, we can say that both `user` and `config` are immediate subdirectories of `/home/`, but `u001` isn't. The same applies if `user`, and `u001` are files (`user` is immediate while `u001` isn't).

So you don't really need recursion or stack to return a list of immediate subdirectories or files.

**EDIT:** I thought that the OP wanted to implement the `subDirectories()` and `filesInDirectories()` functions.

So, you can do something like to print all files (kind of pseudocode):

```
List subd = subDirectories(current_dir);
List files = filesInDirectories(current_dir);

foreach (file in files) {
    print file.name();
}

while (!subd.empty()) {
    dir = subd.pop();

    files = filesInDirectory(dir.name());

    foreach (file in files) {
        print file.name();
    }

    subd.append(subDirectories(dir.path()));
}
```

Comment: True, but the question asks me to print all the files in the file system, not just in the particular directory. Doesn't this mean that I'll need to keep track of which directory I am currently in and also the previous directories so that I can backtrack?

Comment: So, you can use a BFS lile @Michael answered.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what @lqs suggests is indeed an acceptable answer that she might have been looking for: store the full path in a variable, and append the directory name to it if you enter a subdirectory, and clip off the last directory name when you leave it. This way, your full path acts as the pointer to where you currently are in the file system.

Because the full path is always modified at the end, the full path behaves (not surprisingly) as your stack.

Interview questions aside, I think I would still pick a real stack over string manipulation though...